# Python circular dependency

Tags: python

First serious python project and first question on stack :).

I'm building a GUI with different screens. I have a BaseScreen class with all common values, and each specific screen inherits from it and is in its own .py file for organization. Most screens will contain the 'homerow' a row of 5 buttons that change between the screens and this is defined in BaseScreen.

The problem is; when a homerow button is clicked I need to create an instance of the corresponding screen class to make the change, which requires me importing said screen class. These screen classes already need to import BaseScreen as they inherit from it, thus circular dependency and my program not running.

Wondering what the best ways to solve this and similar problems are? And also is my use of classes and my GUI structure itself ok? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a "circular dependency" that's an issue here unless you're doing something weird. Two objects can certainly refer to each other, e.g. `a = []; b = [a]; a.append(b)`. That said... why does `BaseScreen` need to know about its subclasses...? At the very worst, you can just append those classes at run-time.  e.g. `home_screen.classes.append(other_screen)` Or even have a separate `ScreenManager` which contains a list that you register to at runtime, e.g. `screenmanager.register(other_screen)`; and whenever you want to do something, you use `ScreenManager`.

Comment: I guess this is why people usually create dependency graphs at runtime rather than hardcoding it in some inheritance heirarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Does this illustrate your problem?

base_screen.py

```py
class BaseScreen:
   def click_button(self):
       return BlueScreen()
```

and in blue_screen.py

```py
import BaseScreen
class BlueScreen(BaseScreen):
    ...
```

If that's a good illustration, there's nothing saying you can't do this:

```py
class BaseScreen:
    def click_button(self):
        from blue_screen import BlueScreen
        return BlueScreen()
```

Comment: Yes that's very accurate and your suggestion solved my problem thanks! Why exactly does this work?

Comment: it works because "from blue_screen import ..." doesn't get run until click_button() is called.  When click_button() is called and python imports blue_screen.py, it sees "import BaseScreen", it looks in it's namespaces and says "oh, BaseScreen is already set up, I can skip that!"